# "rumor" vs "unfounded rumor"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

If I'm not wrong, "rumor" means:

> A story or report of uncertain or doubtful truth

and "unfounded" means:

> Having no foundation or basis in fact

If so, what is the difference between an "unfounded rumor" and a "rumor"?

Comment: Are you asking if the 'unfounded' this is redundant?

Comment: @Mitch Yes, you can say that.

Comment: An unfounded rumor is a rumor that is unfounded. Not all rumors are unfounded. Many are, but some are not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *rumor* might be true or untrue. Even if it's untrue, though, it might be based on fact:

> **Fact**: Alice and Bob have been spending a lot of time together.
>   **Rumor**: Alice and Bob are going steady.
>   **Reality**: Alice and Bob are not dating, they are partners for a school project.

In contrast, an *unfounded rumor* would be based on no credible supporting evidence:

> *"I think Alice and Bob are going out!"*
>   *"Really? Why do you say that?"*
>   *"I saw them talking in the hallway."*

(Alice and Bob could have been talking about anything; Alice may have simply dropped a pencil, and Bob was handing it back to her. They may not even know each other's names! That looks like the birth of an *unfounded rumor*.)

Answer (score 2):

A rumor is uncertain or doubtful (but may be true). An unfounded rumor has no foundation or basis in fact (and thus cannot be true).

Comment: The interesting word [*canard* is defined as an unfounded rumor.](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=canard&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=W0LnT5nhFpGe6gGwl43hDg&sqi=2&ved=0CGMQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=c1e99b5acbebabce&biw=1366&bih=551)

Comment: I think that someone who stays with you but doesn't pay rent is an *unfunded roomer*, no?

Comment: Any rumour, well-founded or otherwise, may turn out to be true (which may well surprise the person spreading the rumour).

Comment: Only in an unusual sense of "true". Generally, true means "correspondence between claim and reality", which cannot happen unintentionally. (Just as someone from 1066 couldn't argue that electrons exist and be right by luck because he would have no way to specify an electron as the thing he was claiming existed. You can't form a concept that by luck refers to an electron -- you have to *make* a concept refer to an electron which requires a *way* to refer to an electron. He could do it by observing static electricity, of course, but then it would be founded.)

Comment: @David; 'Little green men live on Mars' is an entirely unfounded statement, both because I am not an astronomer and because astronomers have found no reason to believe it.  It *may* be true nevertheless.

Comment: @TimLymington: If it's entirely unfounded, it is not true. There is no such thing as "accidental truth". Truth is a form of correspondence between concepts and reality which can only be formed intentionally -- a concept cannot "accidentally correspond" to a fact. That's not how human brains work. (If one parrot says "2+2=4" and another says "2+2=5", we don't conclude that the first parrot is better at math because what the parrot says *doesn't* correspond to addition because parrots lack the knowledge to make such a correspondence.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Truth occurs when a statement accords with reality, and is not affected by what you or I may think. You are entitled to use the word differently if you wish, but not to say that your (non-dictionary) definition is the only one possible.

Comment: @TimLymington: It most certainly is affected by what you or I may think because this "accord" can exist only with one half inside a human brain. It cannot be in the statement itself. The meanings of words and concepts are in brains, not in the statements. A statement *itself* cannot accord with reality, only the meaning of the statement can do so -- and there is no meaning independent of the contents of brains.

Answer (score 0):

Unfounded rumor is (possibly) tautologically redundant.